# Creating Ubuntu ssh keys in Windows 10

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I am trying to install Core 20 on RPi4 and cannot get past the email address for my account. If I go to the Ubuntu page to define the ssh keys, it says to use the keys already defined. It does not say how or what OS to generate them on. Is there a way to generate the keys in Windows and enable them in Ubuntu SSH keys page?

Alternatively, is there a way to avoid this unnecessary linkage to ubuntu.com just to run the OS?

---

I have created two RSA keys using PuTTYgen and ssh-keygen but neither of them worked on the SSH keys page (reference "official tutorial" above, step 5, item #3) login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys.

Here's the error message I get when attempting to use those keys:

```
Note: Only SSH v2 keys are supported.
Public SSH Key: Invalid SSH key data: 'c:/users/fgould/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
```

Comment: How to create ssh keys in Windows 10 has nothing to do with Ubuntu, and hence off-topic here. Fortunately you can Google and [find instructions](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/generate-ssh-key-windows-10)

Comment: I have created two rsa keys using PuTTYgen and ssh-keygen but neither of them worked on the SSH keys page (reference "official tutorial" above, step 5, item #3) https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys. Here's the error message I get when attempting to use those keys:

Note: Only SSH v2 keys are supported.
Public SSH Key: Invalid SSH key data: 'c:/users/fgould/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'

Comment: I think he is talking about how to access Ubuntu from Win10, so it's not off-topic.

Comment: This is so convoluted that I've given up on any Ubuntu release for RPi. Besides this stupid ssh-keys issue, I've also tried Ubuntu-Mate and it fails to display my kivy app like the rest of Ubuntu images.

Comment: I am reading between the lines here, but are you sure that you actually want Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Core is designed for IoT and embedded devices. If you want Ubuntu Desktop you should follow the instructions for Ubuntu Desktop on RaspberryPi. It's simple.  You flash an image to the SD card, put the SD card in the pi and plug it in and wait for it to initialize itself.  Then it is ready to use.  BalenaEtcher even makes the flash one step and practically error proof. https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Comment: Not sure which lines you're reading between but my app is for RPi running a slideshow app, and that's it. I consider it an IoT device, which was why I wanted to test Core. As for the desktop, that's what I tried with the last build I installed. Then it was deprecated before I could migrate my OS. I could try the Server but it seems all these options have hurdles that take days to resolve. If there is a way to get the Ubuntu SSO to gen a new v2 key for me, I can try Core. Otherwise, I'll stick with Manjaro and its limitations.

Comment: @Nmath, I didn't ask for your opinion about replacements. There are no instructions for how to get the v2 rsa key to test Core. I already installed the Ubuntu Desktop and it failed to work. Spare me the opinions.

Comment: Is there someone who can read what I originally posted? There are no instructions for rsa v2 keys generation so I can install Core. It appears @Nmath would prefer to argue about different images than provide the information I requested in my original post.